# return statement is not stopping method execution

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Recently, I am facing the strange behavior of iOS compiler. I have written one method named `hasConnectivity`. In this method, first I check that internet connectivity is available using Rechability classes. If yes, then I again check the network by calling NSURLRequest to Apple.

Below is my code:

```
-(BOOL)hasConnectivity {

    if(!isOnline)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"];
    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString* pageData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                          usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"page data=%@",pageData);


    if(pageData)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

When I called this method, Control goes in the first block and executes `return TRUE;` statement so ideally control should return from that point but is not returning from that point. Instead, it is jumping to the next block (if condition of pageData) and executes `return FALSE;` statement.

I have restarted Xcode also restarted PC and debugged so many times but still I didn't get the success. If anyone have faced the same problem then please provide me the solution.

Comment: It may seem a step backwards - but toss some `NSLog()` statements in there. There's no way you're hitting that `return` statement and continuing beyond it.

Comment: When you're stepping with the debugger it often jumps around like this.  In particular, there usually is only one actual `return` statement, so control jumps to that from all the `return` statements in the method.  Spend more time debugging and you'll get used to this.

Comment: @ Hot Licks: I also have installed the app in Device without connecting to the mac but it is giving me the same wrong output due to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the build configuration you are building on (probably `Debug` if you didn't change the defaults) have the optimizations turned off:

[image]

Having the optimizations turned on while debugging can cause weird issues like this.

Comment: I checked that, It is same as you have mentioned here.